# Is C++ compiler allowed to convert last usage of lvalue to rvalue implicitly?

Tags: c++, copy-elision

According to C++ standard:

> Copy elision is one of the two allowed forms of optimization,
> alongside allocation elision and extension, (since C++14)

And if I recall correctly, copy elision is only allowed in return, throw, catch, and yield statement.

In that case, for code like this:

```
void func(type x)
{
    auto y = bar();

    // do something with y

    x.foo = y; // Can this be optimized?

    return;
}
```

Is it theoretically permitted by the standard for compiler to use move constructor on lvalue `y` (potentially by converting it to xvalue implicitly) suppose the compiler is smart enough to figure out that the conversion is safe/equivalent (unlike the corner case mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45844034/4794308)).

Comment: *Can this be optimized?*  No.  *Should I always use `std::move()` for the last usage of a local L-value?*  Mostly.

Comment: Thank you @L.F.! I would to learn more if you could expand a bit on your comment. e.g. why last usage like this cannot be optimized? Is it because of some technical hard blocker or simply for compatibility with existing compiler implementation?

Comment: @LifuHuang although the dupe doesn't ask quite the same question I think you will find it will answer all of your doubts

Comment: Thank you @bolov for providing the link. While I do understand there are cases where the last usage of local variable can NOT be optimized by an automatic conversion to r-value (just like how compiler won't respect all `inline`). My question is different from the dupe because I want to understand is it ALLOWED for a compiler to do such optimization in the future suppose it's smart enough to figure out it's not a corner case? Edited my answer to reflect my original intention. Thanks!

Comment: @LifuHuang the dupe does answer that: no, it cannot because there cannot exist a consistent rule to determine the last usage of a variable.

Comment: there is work done (I think by Herb Sutter) on a proposal to add "kinds" of parameters like `in` `out` `forward` and `forward` would allow just one use and that would be move by default.

Comment: Some other languages (e.g., Rust) do take the ownership of `y` (i.e., move from `y`) in an access like `x.foo = y;`, and prevent any further use of `y` at compile-time.  C++, however, does not provide such guarantees except in a few limited cases (e.g., `return`), so copying is invoked in most cases.  It is theoretically possible to revise the standard to allow such optimizations, but the benefit doesn't seem to justify the cost, complexity, and inconsistency.